# jquery and ajax async post back

Tags: jquery, ajax

Hi I am using jquery to have the sliding effect, kwicks effect, slideup and fancybox in a single page. everyhting works perfectly until the ajax postback but after that none of the jquery functions seems to work. any ideas will be great

Comment: i tried using the pageload but no luck. also tried to register the clientscript codebehind still it doesn't seem to work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks as though your UpdatePanel is breaking your javascript. The key is to remember when it does a postback these are not the same elements that your javascript was originally tied to. Rebinding after the postback will fix your problem; all this requires is tying some javascript calls to a Microsoft provided call back function:

```
function BindEvents()
{
    //Here your jQuery function calls go
}

var prm = Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance();
prm.add_endRequest(BindEvents);
```

The PageRequestManager will call the BindEvents function after each post back. This can go any where on the page as long as it is there prior to the postback.

Comment: thanks PCasagrande let me try this now

Comment: Should i call all the jquery functions inside the bindevents()?

Comment: Yes. Anything that would affect the contents of the UpdatePanel should be included in there. The name of the function doesn't matter; BindEvents is just what I used. Using a non-anonymous function is also nice because you can call that function to get everything started at initial page load as well. It just makes any changes down the road more tolerable.

Comment: this helps. also I used the endrequest handler to make it work.